# How to use the reduce operation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently trying to simplify the following code written in Javascript

```
let x = 5;
let y = 10;
let z = 19;
let answer;
arrays = ["x", "y", "z"]; 

if("x" in arrays){
      answer = x;           
}

if("x" in arrays && "y" in arrays){
    answer = x + y
}
```

The code will continue on and on for all the possible combinations of x, y and z. What I want to know is how I can simplify the above block of code and achieve the same result.
Thank you.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a problem here. Code review might be a better place for this

Comment: It would help if you could share the _goal_ of this code, rather than just your attempt. Are `x`, `y` and `z` required to be separate variables? Does `arrays` need to be part of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of individual variables, create an object with your name/value pairs. Then it's trivial to iterate over the names in the array, use them to access the values in the object, and add them together. In fact, this is most naturally expressed as a [*reduce*](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation:

```js
let vals = {
    x: 5,
    y: 10,
    z: 19
};

let answer = ["x", "y", "z"].reduce((a, k) => a + vals[k], 0);

console.log(answer);
```